# Redis version requirement for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

I see on M2 [requirements page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) that it says:

> Magento can utilize the following technologies: Redis version 3.0 for page caching and session storage (the latter supported by Magento version 2.0.6 and later only)

I want to clarify if the *can* is a *must*, or I can use Redis 2.8.19, which is the standard EPEL version today. Can I use version 2+ or not?

Answer (score 2):

Both Redis 2.8 and 3.0 is supported by Magento 2

**Difference:**
Redis 3.0 supports up to 64 different databases per instance of the service, while 2.8 allows for only a single database

**Reference:**
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/cloud/project/project-conf-files_services-redis.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From this I understand that Redis is not _required_, but *optional*.

Comment: As a side note, now I have also manage to connect M2 to AWS ElasticCache  with Redis 3.2.4, for those who want a managed service.

Comment: @ElzoValugi Do you use signed request with AWS ElasticCache ?

Comment: @Frank Garnier,  no the traffic is on TCP port 6379 not on HTTP and is internal for the subnets and protected with security groups.

Comment: Ok many thanks, so you have a static IP? Is it working if you scaling up your frontend server automatically ?

Comment: I have a route53 alias for the redis entry point and all application frontends are sending the requests there and this is what I use in the app/etc/env.php